# netty will block another reuqest in one channel when i request loop msg

Tags: netty

i wrote a test to figure out request order :

> netty will block a large msg request until loop request done

when send a large message to server and same time loop 1000 times to send small message ,how to explain this scenario , or i test wrong?

- this is reasonable or the test case is not valid?

this is a demo code below :

```
Channel connect = nettyClient.connect();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(() -> connect.writeAndFlush(largeBytes)
            .addListener(new FutureListener<Void>() {
                public void operationComplete(Future<Void> f) throws Exception {
                    if (f.isSuccess()) {
                        log.info("channel write message success");
                    } else {
                        log.error("write message error:", f.cause());
                    }

                }
            }));


    int times = 1000;
    ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    do {
        executorService1.submit(() -> connect.writeAndFlush("rpcMessage"));
        times--;
    } while (times > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The large may not be transfered from  Netty's buffers to the underlying socket buffer at one time, it may take multiple times to finish.

When the underlying socket send buffer is full or the number of socket write exceeds WRITE_SPIN_COUNT (default is 16), Netty will suspend the large msg sending operation to give other IO operations some opportunities.

When the socket send buffer is available again or it is the turn of the large msg send operation to be executed again, the current send operation will continue

The following is the relevant source code：
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioSocketChannel.java#L386